# Ionic 3 "rxjs" issue with Typescript and "packages.json" file

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm running an Ionic 3 project and I got the series of errors bellow after running `ionic serve -l` on command terminal:

**Erros in picture:**
[image]

**Full errors text:**

> Typescript Error ';' expected.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error ';'
>   expected. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts }
>   export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never; export declare type
>   ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends Array>
>   ? T : never; Typescript Error Expression expected.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error ';'
>   expected. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>   export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never; export declare type
>   ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends Array>
>   ? T : never; Typescript Error ';' expected.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export declare
>   type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T :
>   never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error
>   Expression expected.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export declare
>   type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T :
>   never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error
>   'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot
>   find name 'infer'.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot
>   find name 'T'. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>   } export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never; export declare type
>   ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends Array>
>   ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot find name 'T'.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error 'never'
>   only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts } export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error
>   'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export
>   declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ?
>   T : never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot
>   find name 'infer'.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export declare
>   type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T :
>   never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot
>   find name 'T'. C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>   export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never; export declare type
>   ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends Array>
>   ? T : never; Typescript Error Cannot find name 'T'.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export declare
>   type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T :
>   never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never; Typescript Error 'never'
>   only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
>   C:/crepedelivery/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts export declare
>   type ObservedValueOf = O extends ObservableInput ? T :
>   never; export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray = X extends
>   Array> ? T : never;

Would should I do? That was after an rxjs update I ran.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution, running the command:

`npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save`

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but in our case we were on RXJS 6.0.0 but found this line added

```
import {parseJson} from "@angular/cli/utilities/json-file";
```

and that was the source of the problem. After removing the line, everything was OK